# How to get path of selected file while browsing from an import wizard in eclipse plug-in

Tags: import, eclipse-plugin, wizard

In my plugin I am trying to make a menu named `Import`. Its action will directly open Import Wizard. In Import Wizard I have to choose a path through a browse button. Now I want to use this path in my plugin. How can I get this path?

Comment: What Import Wizard are you talking about?

Comment: @greg-449 Check this : http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/Image263_import_zip.png

Comment: The standard wizards don't provide a way to find out what they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like greg said, you won't be able to get that info from the standard wizards.

You would have to implement your own wizard and save the variable of the path in the `performFinish()` method somewhere like the preferences or in the context.